# recaptcha is always incorrect php and boostrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, captcha, recaptcha

I am making a login page for my website. I am using the standard recaptcha to verify new accounts, but my recaptcha always comes back as incorrect. I have tried all the "standard" fixes that are listed on stackoverflow. I have zero tables in my code (am using bootstrap 3.x), and I pulled the recaptcha.php file from google servers today, it has the new locations for the API. I have no idea why it is doing this. I have checked, and double checked my codes but public and private.

Any help would be great. Here are the two pieces of code. First, on my index.php page:

```
            Register:
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="php/verify.php" >

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Username</span>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" >
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Email</span>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
            </div>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">Password</span>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
            </div>

            <?php
              require_once('php/recaptchalib.php');
              $publickey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-changed for security"; // you got this from the signup page
              echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
            ?>

            <button type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Then, here is the verify.php file it goes to:

```
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-changed for safety";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
            $message = "Your CAPTCHA was wrong, please retry.";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('$message');
                    window.location = '../';
                  </script>";

  } 
  else {
            $message2 = "Your CAPTCHA was right!!";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('$message2');
                    window.location = '../';
                  </script>";
  }
```

Comment: `alert('$message')` - really? How can you desecrate a - probably decent-looking - bootstrap site with alert() messages?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the POST values to see what you receive?

Comment: The reason I am using alert is because I couldn't figure out how to display it was incorrect on the same page so it was a gap filler. I'm just starting with PHP I'm no good at it yet :(

Comment: I just contrasted with my last reCaptcha implementation (which is working), and it's almost identical ( but the alert part ). Have you considered, that you could be just failing the captcha? How many times have you tried? Could we have the link to give it a try? I mean... those captchas sometimes are harder to read than you can expect. Also, in such an simple code implementation it's less likely the code is wrong. Are you testing on local or production environment ?

Comment: I am hosting it liveonline -- here is proof http://imgur.com/JggAXBY